# How to make prev&next image of slider darker

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I found this example of a slider https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/daLzpL.

I made prev and next image darker by adding:
 `prev.children(':nth-last-child(3)').css('filter', "brightness(50%)");`, and
 `prev.children(':nth-last-child(1)').css('filter', "brightness(50%)");`

But It's not working on the last slide for the previous image. Has anyone got an idea?

```
  $('.carousel-item', '.show-neighbors').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (! next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
}).each(function(){
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (! prev.length) {
    prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
  }
   prev.children(':nth-last-child(3)').css('filter', "brightness(50%)");
   prev.children(':nth-last-child(1)').css('filter', "brightness(50%)");
    prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet demonstrating your problem?

Comment: sry, I yesterday registered here. Don't know a lot of. You could paste my code into https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/daLzpL js file and you would see.

Comment: I see there is already an answer to your question but for next time when you press `ctr + m` when creating a question you get the snippet promp and you can write your code there so people can easely repreduce the issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chain the `.css()` instruction after the `.clone().appendTo()` instructions on both the `next` and the `prev` sections *(as indicated by my "NEXT LINE DOWN" comments).*

```
$('.carousel-item', '.show-neighbors').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (! next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  //NEXT LINE DOWN
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).css('filter', "brightness(50%)");
}).each(function(){
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  if (! prev.length) {
    prev = $(this).siblings(':last');
  }
  //NEXT LINE DOWN
  prev.children(':nth-last-child(2)').clone().prependTo($(this)).css('filter', "brightness(50%)");
});
```